# How we can set Pagination as per custom parameter in Vtiger

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

We are displaying today followup on Dashboard. Like

[image]

While user click on view link filter data is displayed on SalesOrder module on Vtiger list view page

[image].

But while we click on pagination count it displays different.

[image]

I have update query in list view while my custom parameter pass from dashboard and I will get result accordingly on list page but I don't know how we can set pagination according to my custom parameter or Custom query.

Answer (score 1):

In Vtiger, Any Module List page pagination count will come from `"getListViewCount()"` function.

We have put this function in our salesOrder/models/Listview.php

After that i have taken one hidden variable in `ListViewContents.tpl` file for our custom parameter also we have update `getDefaultParams` Event from `layouts\vlayout\modules\Vtiger\resources\List.js` and pass our custom parameter with custom variable.

with the help of that we can perfect count for custom parameter query.

here you can see the result,

[image]

now, click on view link

[image]